# How can I reverse a string using two separate byte arrays?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, reverse, masm

**How can I reverse a string using two separate byte arrays?**

Write a program using the LOOP instruction with indirect addressing that copies a string from source to target, reversing the character order in the process.

Use the following variables:

```
source BYTE "This is the source string",0 
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP ('#')
```

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string in assembly language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368586/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-assembly-language)

Comment: I agree that this is close to the How to reverse a string, but it is a bit different since it's how to copy it (to a new location) rather than how to output a string backwards.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty straightforward. Use indirect addressing (in other words, don't use the memory addresses directly but reference them, through a register perhaps) and reverse the string.  For example, here are some barebones assuming that you have already defined source and target:

```
MOV SI, source   ; Get source address
MOV DI, (target + SIZEOF source)   ; Get the ending address for target
LOOP:
  MOV AL, [SI]   ; Get a byte
  MOV [DI], AL   ; Store a byte
  INC SI         ; Move forward one in source
  DEC DI         ; Move back one in target
  CMP AL, 0      ; Have we reached the zero termination?
  JNZ LOOP
RET
```

This is by no means meant to be complete or functional. You may, for instance, need to figure out a better way to figure out the length of SOURCE dynamically. :)  However, I don't want to take the joy of learning away from you.  This should  be at least a good starting point.

Comment: _"`target + SIZEOF source`"_. Wouldn't you need to pre-decrement `DI` within the loop then?

Comment: Possibly... As I said, I'm not really trying to solve it for him, just get him started.

Comment: can you guys give me answer please

Comment: @sinan: That is an answer.  If you don't understand it, then you need to get more help from your professor / TA / textbook / online tutorials.